# Intellij 2022.3.1 won't load the AspectJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, aspectj

I'm building a Minecraft plugin that passes the functions to a Lua interpreter, and after exploring all other options for doing hooks without manually writing everything (i.e. using a built in function from Spigot that lets me easily intercept every event handler; I am not able to use arguments with this, making it worthless for my case) I've discovered my best option is AspectJ.

I installed the latest version of IntelliJ, then installed the [relevant plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4679-aspectj) and followed the instruction to "add a library containing aspectjrt.jar to my project" (I added org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.19 through build.gradle, and added 'include 'aspectjrt:1.9.19'' to my settings.gradle). It also says to add a facet, but I can't do that due to the error "Requires plugin 'com.intellij.aop' to be installed." I can't find any reference to a dedicated AOP plugin for IntelliJ, in fact I'm told the AspectJ plugin is supposed to add support for it. There seems to be no other reference to this error online.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to delete the `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory while the IDE is closed. If the problem remains contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for future assistance.

Comment: What exactly tells you that AspectJ is not supported or popular anymore? The latest AspectJ version 1.9.19 supports Java 19 preview features, and AspectJ is used stand-alone as well as within the Spring framework for both basic Spring AOP pointcut parsing/matching and advanced use cases with native AspectJ (e.g. call or control flow matching, intercepting non-Spring code, intercepting private methods or field read/write access).

Comment: That you have problems getting it to work in IntelliJ IDEA, does not mean it is unsupported. I use it in IDEA 2022.3.1 every day. Your opinionated entry statement does not make you a lot of friends here.

Comment: I have removed the entry statement.